# Is it possible to make an "Ignore No More" app for iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

This Android app gives parents the ability to lock their childs phone if they arent returning their parents phone calls. Im wondering if this idea is possible on iphone, given that Apple is super strict on the networking level?

Is it possible to send a signal to lock out a user from their phone or to disable their ability to text/surf web/make calls?

I doubt this is possible but if anyone has any ideas would be a great learning project for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Find my iPhone would be a good candidate for this right out of the box. If the phone is on the parent's account the parent (at any time) can log into iCloud.com and lock the phone and place a message on the screen. It also allows for dialling to emergency numbers and a specified "Call Home" number. You can also see where the phone is on a map.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. iOS applications cannot interfere with the normal operation of the device.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just one more followup question. What about if hardware was introduced to send a bluetooth signal to a device to stop it from receiving/sending calls/texts...etc

Comment: or if someone is on ur wifi network or anything like that.

Comment: Neither Bluetooth devices nor devices on a wireless network have the ability to do that.